# And/Or elemental-wise for list of bools in python

Tags: python, list, boolean

I have two lists of Bools in python:

```
l1 = [True, False, True]
l2 = [False, True, True]
```

And I wish to do elemental-wise comparison And/Or for them. I wish to get:

```
l3 = [False, False, True] # elemental-wise And
l4 = [True, True, True] # elemental-wise Or
```

So I simply put:

```
l3 = l1 and l2
l4 = l1 or l2
```

But the result behaves unexpectedly as:

```
l3=[False, True, True] (which is l2)
l4=[True, False, True] (which is l1)
```

How can I accomplish the elemental-wise comparison nice and clean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension

```py
l3 = [(i and j) for i,j in zip(l1,l2)]
l4 = [(i or j) for i,j in zip(l1,l2)]
```

When you are doing

```py
l3 = l1 and l2
l4 = l1 or l2
```

then it is getting reduced to

```py
l3 = bool(l1) and l2
l4 = bool(l1) or l2
```

Now since `l1` is non-empty list, so
`bool(l1) = True`

Now, what I assume in the case of `l3 = l1 and l2`, `l1` is evaluated as `True` so for `short circuit evaluation`, it returns `l2`.

In case of `l4 = l1 or l2`, again due to `short circuit evaluation`, `l1` is returned since `l1` is `True`.

So, you are getting the result like that.
`short circuit evaluation` is nothing but--

1. In the case of `A and B`, if A evaluates to True go on evaluating B and return the result of B. If A evaluates to False, then no point of evaluating B. Return the result of A.

```py
False and print('hello')
>>> False
True and print('hello')
>>> hello
```

2. In the case of `A or B`, if A evaluates to True, then there is no point in evaluating B. Just return the result of A. If A evaluates to False, then return the result of B.

```py
True or (1/0)
>>> True
False or (1/0)
>>> ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
```

---

Note:

```py
bool([]) = False
bool([1,2,'a']) = True
bool(['False']) = True
```

---

Comment: Neat! Though this would get pretty long if there were more than two lists.

Comment: The short circuit evaluation is very inconvenient when using lists of Boolean for slicing.

Comment: @pphero0287 Did you try my answer?

Comment: @Ann Zen, yes and thanks, yours is a similar solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the built-in [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) and [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) methods in a list comprehension:

```
l1 = [True, False, True]
l2 = [False, True, True]

l3 = [all(z) for z in zip(l1, l2)]
l4 = [any(z) for z in zip(l1, l2)]

print(l3)
print(l4)
```

Output

```
[False, False, True]
[True, True, True]
```

You can also use the built-in [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) method:

```
l1 = [True, False, True]
l2 = [False, True, True]

l3 = map(all, zip(l1, l2))
l4 = map(any, zip(l1, l2))

print(list(l3))
print(list(l4))
```

Output:

```
[False, False, True]
[True, True, True]
```